Brain teaser: 4 lightbulbs at the corners of a square
There are 4 lightbulbs on the corners of a square A,B,C,D, initially they are all on. Whenever you take a step forward, if the previous bulb was on, you switch the next one (turn it on if it was off and off if it was on), if it was off, you don't do anything. Eg. start from A and move to B, you turn B off because A was on. Then since B is turned off, you won't change C so you leave it on. Then you turn off D because C was turned on and leave A on when you get back to A. So after 4 steps the constellation would be
$$A:\text{on},B:\text{off}, C:\text{on}, D:\text{off}$$
Then the question is, what happens on the 1000th step.
My approach is to repeat the steps until I find a constellation which repeats itself, then use modular approach to find the 1000th step.
So this is by no means an easy way, I programmed this on python and I get [0,0,1,0], which appears first at step 39 until step 42 then again at step 99 until 102 and then it repeat every 60 steps since it appears at 100 and will repeat every 60 steps, then it will also clearly appear at 1000 as well since 900 is divisible by 60.
Anyway, I am just wondering if there is a much better approach that I am completely missing.
Thanks for the help!
The program if anyone wants to check:

bulbs = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1]
for i in range(1000):
if bulbs[i%4] == 1:
   bulbs[(i+1)%4] ^= 1 
   print(i+1,bulbs) if bulbs==[0,0,1,0] else None
print(bulbs)



Hint: representing the state as a 4-vector in $\mathbb{F}_2$, can you encode one 4-step "cycle" as a 4 × 4 matrix?

@NaïmFavier I mean yes but i don't really see how this helps me.

@NaïmFavier nice. Is there an easy way to find the order of the matrix? It seems that whatever approach you use, the crux is finding how many steps you have to take before the pattern repeats.

Hint 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

@ChrisLewis I don't know, but this is at least amenable to optimisation.

Something to try would be to compute the periods for different values of 4 and plug the resulting sequence into the OEIS.

My initial approach was to keep track of the setup every four steps (eg by encoding in binary). It's not too hard to find how often the pattern repeats. It's nice that every possible pattern occurs (except having all lights off). This isn't always the case if you change the number of lights.

@ChrisLewis my initial approach was the same but now i realize that due to this i missed the fact that the pattern [1,1,1,1] occurs every 15th step this might actually be the only straightforward way to solve this. Then 10th step would be the 1000th step too because at 990 [1,1,1,1] will occur.

@SonMatBukucu well, that's how I found the period. Once you have that it's trivial, but it is a bit tedious to work through. Like you I wonder if there's a more elegant approach.

@ChrisLewis thanks for the help. I will check the other hint, but not sure if it would be possible to come up with a trick using that. I will update if i find a more elegant solution.

Since OP has done the brute force approach in the comments, let's approach this theoretically. Make sure you read the bolded part at the end.
We work in $\mathbb{F}_2$.
Step 1: Let's find the transition matrix to

If the first coordinate is 1, then toggle the 2nd light.
Shift every coordinate up 1, so that we're standing a the "1st light".

This is represented by
$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
 $
Step 2: Find the characteristic polynomial of $P$.
I'd skip the algebraic manipulation and you can use your favorite approach to show that it is $ x^4 + x^ 3 + 1$.
Step 3: Find the period of $P$, which applies to all vectors, not just $\begin{pmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$.
To do so, we want the smallest $n$ such that $x^n \equiv 1 \pmod{x^4 + x^3 + 1 }$.
Once again I'd skip the algebraic manipulation, and just state that the period is 15 because
$$ x^{15} - 1 = (x^4 + x^3 + 1) ( x^{11} + x^{10} + x^9 + x^8    +x^4 + x^3 + 1 ). $$
Note:

I iteratively calculated $x^n \pmod{x^4+x^3+1}$ as it was easy to multiply by $x$ and replace $x^4$ with $x^3 + 1$.
You can find the above factorization easily by looking at $x^n - 1 = (x^4+x^3+1) (x^{n-4} + ...)$, realize that we have a $x^{n-4}x^3 = x^{n-1}$ term so need to add $x^{n-5}$ to the factor, realize that we have a $x^{n-5}x^3 = x^{n-2}$  so need to add $x^{n-6}$ to the factor, etc.  Stop when you only have 1 term left.
I tried looking at cyclotomic polynomials, but it wasn't easy to see that $x^4 + x^3 + 1 \mid \Phi_{15}(x)$.

Step 4: Since $1000 \equiv 10 \pmod{15}$, we just need to find what happens 10 steps in, then adjust for the placement of A, B, C, D.
This is left to the reader.
Step 3 revisited: While that was all good in theory ....
For each $n$, the remainder is a degree at most 3 polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$, which has $2^4 = 16$ possibilities. So if we consider 17 values of $x^n$, by the pigeonhole principle, 2 of the remainders will be the same, and we can take the difference to find the period, so the period is $\leq 17$.
Furthermore, in step 4, we need to find some of $P^n \begin{pmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ to calculate the answer.
So we might just as well simply brute forced our way, knowing that we need at most $n \approx 17$ steps to find the period of this vector (not necessarily of all vectors), and then find what the final value is.

Thank you! This is great. I also found one corollary in the book introduction to finite fields and their application which states:
if $f\in\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of degree $m$ then $ord(f)$ divides $q^m-1$.
Applied in this case we get that the order divides $2^4-1=15$ and we don't even need to compute the expansion as the order clearly cannot be 3 or 5 (the other divisors of 15)

@SonMatBukucu Yes it's a standard result in field theory, but I didn't know want to assume that knowledge.

Consider a different but related game.  You start with the four light-bulbs in a square, and are at position $A$. After you move to position $B$, and shift its value if $A$ is turned on, a new operation is applied. You and every light-bulb move back by 1 position. Ie. position $C$ takes the value had by $D$, position $B$ takes the value had by $C$, etc.
So if the initial configuration of values were $(a,b,c,d)$, the new values would be $(a \oplus b, c,d,a)$ .
So we get: $(a,b,c,d) \rightarrow (a \oplus b, c,d,a)$.
This is obtained by applying your rule (when starting at position one),
$(a,b,c,d) \rightarrow (a, a\oplus b,c,d)$, followed by the "move everything back one position" rule, namely:  $(a, a\oplus b,c,d) \rightarrow (a \oplus b, c,d,a)$.
The advantage of this game is that you always stay at position one. We're just considering how the light-bulbs move relative to you, rather than how you move relative to the light-bulbs. If we consider the $k$'th move configuration of this game, we can recover the $k$'th move configuration of or initial unmodified game game by just "moving everything (including you) forward $k$ positions".
The light bulbs can be encoded as values in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (integers modulo $2$), with $1$, being on, $0$ being off, and "flipping $b$ if $a$ is turned on" being represented as the transition $b \rightarrow a + b$, $\;$as $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
The "move everything forward by $1$" matrix $M$ encodes the transition $(a,b,c,d) \rightarrow (d,a,b,c)$ by 
$\vec{v} \rightarrow M\vec{v}$, where $\vec{v}$ is a $4$-vector representing the current state. It is given by:
$$M= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 &1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The transition matrix of our modified game, $N$, encodes the transition:
$(a,b,c,d)\rightarrow (a \oplus b, c,d,a)$  and is given by:
$$N= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Our aim is to compute the values of the unmodified game after the $1000$'th move, starting with $\vec{v} = (1,1,1,1)$. So we must compute  $\vec{v}_{1000} = M^{1000}N^{1000} \; \vec{v}$.
In $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, $M$ is a matrix of period $4$, and $N$ is a matrix of period $15$ (to do: give a theory-based argument for the period of $N$. I just brute-forced it). So we must compute $M^0 N^{10} \; \vec{v}$, giving us $(0,0,1,0)$ as the final answer.

FYI That is the approach I took. Your matrix $N$ is my matrix $P$.
